# Manually Following Referrals Vs automatic following

Tags: ldap, jndi

I just started exploring JNDI. I had a doubt in referral concept. I know there are 3 ways to handle referals (ignore, follow, throw). My concern is, Javadoc is telling there are two ways we can handle referrals, one by following and another by handling the exception (javax.naming.ReferralException). My concern is which one I should use. Can I follow the referrals blindly (or) do I need to process the exception javax.naming.ReferralException manually. Can some one suggest me which one is better?

Reference
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/referral/follow.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/referral/throw.html

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing better or worse. If you follow referrals, it incurs a cost - cost of forwarding the request over the network. It can slow down your LDAP query. If you are sure you can live up with the query results without need of chasing a referral if it is encountered, use 'throw', else, 'follow'.

With Microsoft AD at least, I have always use 'follow' referrals. The best practice though is to use a Global Catalog (GC) with AD.

For details of internals of referral chasing in AD, refer to: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2009/07/06/referral-chasing/